# Issue while reading delimited flat file data due to ^M char

Tags: controls, spring-batch

I've an issue with reading records from flat file due to ^M special char. When there is ^M char found data it, Its takeup as new line and due to this my data is completly messed up in target the system.

I am using FlatFileItemReader to read the file. I cant change the source file. Is there any way to handle this issue.

### sample File:

### 1|2234|3|stu ID|secutiry||rak

1|2243|4|srch|ffh

### hhy||kum

### 1|2234|3|stu ID|secutiry||rak

Comment: did you look around, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746226/special-characters-m-appearing-at-the-end-of-line-in-file-if-seen-on-unix-but ?

Comment: I cant modified the source by removing ^M characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pass to the `FlatFileItemReader` a `BufferedReaderFactory` that returns a subclass of `BufferedReader` where `BufferedReader::readline(boolean)` has been overridden in a way that it doesn't treat `'\r'` specially.